# Does 'scenery' affect anything other than guests thoughts on the ride?

Tags: planet-coaster

Planet Coaster was released recently so there is little information on some of its mechanics. The game differentiates itself from other park management games with its scenery rating.

I am aware this rating affects guests' perceptions of the rides and buildings but was wondering if it affects anything else such as excitement, willingness to pay more for the ride, or other things?

Comment: I made some additional experiments to find out how the queue scene rating is calculated exactly and summarized my findings [in a new self-answered question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/291889/how-is-the-queue-scene-rating-calculated).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will notice that the first page of each ride info window has a percent rating for "queue scenery". This rating has some influence on how much people are willing to pay for the ride. I tested this with two identical rides. One had a completely unstyled queue with 0%, the other a very nicely designed one with a scenery rating of 100%. It did not affect the excitement, fear or nausea rating, but people were willing to pay roughly 1 dollar more for the styled ride before they started to complain.

Comment: Things to find out: 1. is the scenery bonus on expected ticket price flat or percentual? 2. how exactly is the bonus calculated? While experimenting I got the impression that variety matters over quantity, but I still need to confirm that experimentally. 3. what objects are counted as belonging to a ride? 4. Rollercoasters and track rides appear to have a separate scenery rating in their test results, how does that factor in?