# How is the queue scene rating calculated?

Tags: planet-coaster

I noticed that all rides have a "Queue scene rating" on their Overview tab. I also noticed that guests will pay about 50% more for rides with a good queue scene rating. How exactly is this rating calculated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After lots of experimentation in sandbox mode I think that I can say this:

- Every building part and scenery object has a scene value and an effect radius. These values can be vastly different, but do not necessarily correlate with price or size.
- Each of these objects affects all queue tiles within its radius. The total scenery value of each queue tile is the sum of the objects which affect it.
- Effect radius is limited horizontally but not vertically. That means scenery can be placed far above or below the queue and still affect it fully.
- The scene rating of a ride is the average of all tiles of its queue.

That means in effect:

- Rides with short queues are easier to style than rides with long queues
- Compact and winding queues gain more score from each tile than long, stretched ones.
- Placing scenery very close to the queue is good for two reasons. First, more scenery objects can affect the queue and second, each object will affect more queue tiles.
- When you don't care at all about aesthetics or realism, you can move all the scenery exactly below the queues and a hundred meter below ground.

**Update Version 1.1.3:** While the patchlog says that "Various improvements have been made to how guests assess ride queues", none of these seem to have invalidated any of the above points.

Comment: That's interesting that there is no vertical restriction for the effect radius. 
With regard to the queue styles, do you mean that an "S" queue will give more score than an "I" queue of similar height, i.e 3 tiles straight?

Comment: @BanhMiDacBiet When you place the scenery inside the bends of the s-curve, then the score will likely be higher.

Comment: Ah, because then it'll "touch" every queue tile around it. In time someone will most likely find optimal queue scenery placement in relation to scenery objects. But that's no fun.

Comment: Not sure if it's correct or not but I'd heard or got it into my head that the jewel treasure chest is the most valuable scenery you can place in a queue.